# How to disable automatic renaming of closing HTML tags in VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am new to VS Code custom settings. I don't know from where I turned on the setting for auto renaming the closing tags for HTML language, but I want to turn it off. I am having a hard time working with `.ejs` files because this feature keeps changing my `<%` tags.

I tried `"html.autoClosingTags": false` in my workspace `.json` ('Thought maybe it is related to this') but it's not working.

I have my `.ejs` file associated with `HTML` language.

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.ejs": "html"
  },
```

and I am using **prettier** as a formatter.

```
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
```

my json file.

```
{
  // "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": {
      "foreground": "#1a7a35"
    }
  },
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "ejs": "html"
  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*.ejs": "html"
  },
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorLineNumber.foreground": "#387a38"
  },
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[java]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java"
  },
  "[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.css-language-features"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.independentColorPoolPerBracketType": true,
  "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.sortImports": true
  },
  "editor.autoClosingDelete": "never",
  "html.autoCreateQuotes": false,
  "html.autoClosingTags": false,
  "prettier.bracketSameLine": true,
}
```

Comment: I doubt this comes from your linter, but instead one of the installed extension (maybe even one of the standard extensions) does this renaming. Start by disabling all your 3rd party extensions you have installed and see if that stops the automatic changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings.json file, you have

```json
"editor.formatOnType": true
```

The setting's description:

> Controls whether the editor has linked editing enabled. Depending on the language, related symbols such as HTML tags, are updated while editing.

Either set it to `false`, or just remove that line, since the default value is `false`.